# Dynamically changing variables type

Tags: javascript, numbers, bigint

I am building a factorization program and I would like to change each `BigInt` type to regular `Numbers` when `number <= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

Instead of coding two functions for each case, **it would be nice if I could keep it all into one function which could vary variables types accordingly** *(something like `let myVar = 3n || 3` I guess)*.

```js
function Factorize(dividend) {
  let divisor = 2n; 
  //if number <= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER then let divisor = 2. Same for all other bigInts.
  let method1 = [], method2 = [];
  while (dividend > 1n) {
    if (dividend % divisor === 0n) {
      method1.push(`${divisor}`);
      method2.push(`${dividend} / ${divisor}`);
      dividend /= divisor;
    } else {
      divisor++
    };
  };
  return {
    default: method1,
    detailed: method2,
    get isPrime() {
      return this.default.length === 1 && this.default[0] !== 2;
    }
  };
};

const number = parseInt(prompt());

console.log(Factorize(BigInt(number)));
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the difficulty? Your comment contains half the required code already:

```
  if (dividend <= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) {
    divisor = 2;
    dividend = Number(dividend);
  }
```

And then you only need to replace the two strict equality comparisons `=== 0n` and `!== 2` with their non-strict variants. `0 == 0n` returns `true`, `0n === 0n` returns false.

Some other things worth mentioning:

(1) This method for factorization is extremely slow. There are prime numbers well below `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` for which this will take *months*. Depending on your use case, limiting the input size or implementing some sort of timeout (e.g., returning an error if a certain number of iterations wasn't enough to find the complete result) may be more important than supporting BigInts at all. (For inputs that have only small prime factors, even extremely huge inputs will still terminate quickly, so it's certainly possible to exceed Number range (even `Number.MAX_VALUE`) while still only taking a few milliseconds.)

(2) Using `parseInt` to get your input means that you're limiting yourself to Number precision; converting that Number to a BigInt afterwards doesn't bring the lost bits back. For example, if someone enters `'12157665459056928801'` (which is 3n ** 40n), `parseInt` will truncate that and your program will hence compute the wrong result. To avoid that, use the fact that the `BigInt()` constructor can convert strings directly, i.e.: `BigInt(prompt())`.

(3) While it's sometimes possible to write code that can work on both Numbers and BigInts, doing so is generally not recommended (and often not even useful), because the two types of values (intentionally!) behave differently in a number of ways (otherwise we wouldn't need both of them), so there is a large risk of such code not doing what you think it'll do. In this particular case it should be okay; I'm just advising not to generalize from this example.

Comment: Could you please clarify when saying, "This method for factorization is extremely slow". Do you have any suggestions? I've looked up factorization algorithms written in js on stackoverflow and this one is the fastest.

Comment: Try 99999989, 999999929, 9999999929 and you'll see: expect around 2s, 20s, 3min, depending on your hardware; and that's just 8-10 decimal digits. Every digit will multiply time by 10, MAX_SAFE_INTEGER has 16 digits. Prime factorization is known to be a computationally hard problem; many cryptography schemes rely on that. You can save some time by trying fewer candidates, e.g. skip all even numbers (except `2`, of course), stop when `divisor**2>dividend`. There are also probabilistic primality tests, e.g. Miller-Rabin, that can tell you when it's pointless to even try factorizing.